# How do I find an atom in VMD by using its index

Tags: computational-chemistry

For my work I was asked to run a computational NMR of a *mostly* water structure and then asked to show which hydrogen in this structure correspond to what chemical shifts

I am visualizing the structure in VMD and by clicking on the hydrogens manually I get useful info like its index which corresponds 1:1 as the order they appear on my separate chemical shift data file

My problem is that although I can write down that Hydrogen number 84 has a chemical shift of XXX, I can not as easily find Hydrogen number 84 from VMD itself, in the graphical interface. I know there is a command called atomselect but I am having a VERY hard time getting it to work and was wondering if anyone can give me some guidance on how I can easily look up specific hydrogens  though Identifiable keywords like its "index" witout having to resort to random guess clicking until I find the right one

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You do not need atomselect to do this in VMD, you can do this from the GUI as well.

##### 1) Open the file with VMD

##### 2) From the menu bar go to Graphics > Representations...

[image: VMD picture 1]

I would recommend using `Lines` or `CPK` as drawing method for the main system (selected atoms = "all"), as this gives small atom size in display.

##### 3) Click on "Create Rep" button and a new representation will be created with the atom selection "all"

Delete "all" and type "index 10" to select only atom 10 for the visualization, then click "Apply". Then change drawing method to "VDW" to highlight that atom (it will become bigger). Alternatively you can change the colouring scheme to highlight atom. [Keep in mind that in VMD, atom number counting starts from $0$]

[image: VMD picture 2]

The result would look like this:

[image: VMD picture 3]

You can see that atom number 10 is now clearly visible among all others. (I am using a large system with ~ 3000 atoms so there are a lot of atoms on the screen; with smaller systems, you would be able to see the highlighted atom even more clearly.)

VMD can also select atoms in many other ways. You can go to the "Selections" tab in the Graphical Representations window to see all of the options available.

---

As an aside, VMD's main strength is visualising a large number of atoms, it is mainly targeted at molecular dynamics. If you are calculating NMR, I assume you are using a small system (~50 atoms max) and using some quantum chemistry software like Gaussian or Orca. For those, there are many other visualisation programs which would be easier to use I believe. For example, [Avogadro](https://avogadro.cc/) can read output files from many quantum chemistry codes and visualise the structure. In the "Display types" windows on the left, you can turn on `Label` which will show the atom numbers of each atom in the display:

[image: Avogadro display atom number]

Then you can see the atom number of each atom in one display, instead of highlighting one by one in VMD.